# Calculate the angles

Tags: geometry

I have already asked this question but I asked it quite sloppy (I left out a vital part and added it afterwards):

We have the following situation:
[image]

in which we are given that $AB // CD$, $AC // DE$ and $BD //CE$. We also know that $x,y \in \{20,30\}$ and then we have to know the value of $x$ and $y$. The drawing suggests that we should prove that $x > y$ so that $x = 30$ and $y=20$ must hold, but I can't find a proof.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be respectively $\angle ADB$ and $\angle ACB$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes! The excercise shouldn't be too hard, but I can't solve it :(.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the point where the diagonals cross. Then triangles $AMB$ and $CMD$ are similar.

Since $|DM|<|CM|$ and $|AM|>|BM|$ we also have
$$ \tag{*}\frac{|AM|}{|DM|}>\frac{|BM|}{|DM|}>\frac{|BM|}{|CM|} $$

We can find $x$ and $y$ from these ratios by solving two SAS triangles -- more specifically we get (by drawing the perpendicular from $D$ to $AM$) that
$$ x = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{|AM|}{|DM|}\frac{1}{\sin 50^\circ}-\frac1{\tan 50^\circ}\right)+40^\circ $$
which varies monotonically with $|AM|/|DM|$, and $y$ varies in *exactly the same way* with $|BM|/|CM|$.

Because $\tan^{-1}$ is strictly increasing, this means that (*) implies $x>y$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you obtain that $x = tan^{-1}(...) + 40^o$? I think your solution is correct and it's quite nice, but I don't see how you get that value of $x$?

Comment: @Tim: It wasn't actually right; I've fixed the formula. If the perpendicular from $D$ intersects $AM$ at $P$, then I get $$\tan(x-40^\circ)=\frac{|AP|}{|DP|}=\frac{|AM|}{|DP|}-\frac{|PM|}{|DP|}=\frac{|AM|}{|DM|\sin 50^\circ}-\frac1{\tan 50^\circ}$$

Comment: The important, intuitive, point is that when $|DM|$ and the 50° angle are fixed, $x$ will increase monotonically with $|AM|$, and by similarity the dependence will actually be on $|AM|/|DM|$. The nitty-gritty details of the trigonometry are just for complete rigor.

Comment: @TimHellemans: Something's wrong with the exercise. If $x=30,y=20$, then $AD=AB=BC$. It then follows that $x=y$ due to symmetry.

Comment: @QuangHoang: How do you get that? In this situation $AD$ makes an angle of 60° to the horizontal, whereas $BC$ is at 40° to the horizontal. Why would they be equal (going between the two same horizontal lines)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: can you draw that trapezoid?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Hm, I see it now. Your point is that the angles would make $DAB$ and $ABC$ isosceles. You should probably post that as an answer.